# Unable to generate logs for the installation of Erlang and RabbitMQ installer in Windows

Tags: logging, installation, rabbitmq, erlang-otp

I am using Erlang version 25.2.3 and RabbitMQ version 3.11.10. I am using .exe installer to install it in windows machine silently. I want to generate logs for the installation by using both installers.

I know, I can generate logs for the installation if I use .msi type installer (e.g. MongoDB) like below:

Steps to generate logs for .msi type installation:

1. Open a command prompt, where the installation file is located.
2. Run the command: msiexec /i "mongodb-database-tools-windows-x86_64-100.6.1.msi" /L*V "mongodb_tools.log"

But I am unable to do that for the Erlang and RabbitMQ installer.

I tried the following steps to generate logs for Erlang installation. But it didn't generate any installation log.

1. Open a command prompt, where the installation file is located.
2. Run the command: "otp_win64_25.2.3.exe" /L*V "erlang.log"

The above steps also doesn't work for RabbitMQ installer.

**How can I generate logs for the installation of Erlang and RabbitMQ?**

Answer (score 0):

Erlang and RabbitMQ use the NSIS installation system, not MSI. Check the NSIS documentation for how to enable logging (if it's even possible).